# ImportError: No module named spiders

Tags: python, scrapy

`from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider`

Rule is giving error

1. I am using ubuntu
2. I have Scrapy 0.24.5 and Python 2.7.6
3. I tried with tutorial project of scrapy
4. I am working on pycharm

Comment: I think it's likely that you're trying to follow a tutorial for the more recent release of scrapy and that `scrapy.spiders` is not a module name in v0.24.5

Answer (score 2):

This error can also be caused if, in your `settings.py` file, you have the following:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['spiders']
```

If you don't have that module in your project the error you provide will be raised because scrapy is attempting to look in that module for spiders to use.

Answer (score 1):

So, as I said in my comment, it looks like there is no module named `spiders` in v0.24.5. Here is the [github page](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tree/69ecd6ded72971d510bac40fdde6dd8d160259b5) for that release, and while it looks like there is a module called `spider` there is no `spiders`. I would suggest downloading the most recent version of scrapy if you plan on continuing to follow the updated tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete `__init__.py` from any place in your project directory. Just because it's empty doesn't mean you don't need it. Create a new empty file called `__init__.py` in your spiders directory, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure scrapy is installed. Try running scrapy when your terminal directory is python, or you can try to update scrapy..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the project name from `instagram` to `insta` because it got confused when I was using the `python-instagram` Python package but forgot to change it in the `insta/insta/settings.py` file. I did so and it worked:

```
  1 # Scrapy settings for instagram project
  2 #
  3 # For simplicity, this file contains only the most important settings by
  4 # default. All the other settings are documented here:
  5 #
  6 #     http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/settings.html
  7 #
  8 
  9 BOT_NAME = 'insta'
 10 BOT_VERSION = '1.0'
 11 
 12 SPIDER_MODULES = ['insta.spiders']
 13 NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'insta.spiders'
 14 USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the tutorial you are fallowing and your version is mismatched.
Simply replace this **(scrapy.Spider)** with **(scrapy.spiders.Spider)**.
Spider function is put into spiders module.